# Check if $\sqrt{x^2+\sin(x^2)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$

Tags: calculus, limits

I have this problem :

Check if $\sqrt{x^2+\sin(x^2)}$ is differentiable at $x=0$

This is what I did, but it went wrong for some reason :

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\sqrt{h^2+\sin(h^2)}}{h}$$

Using L'hopital $("\frac{0}{0}")$

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\frac{(2h+2 h \cos(h^2))}{2 \sqrt{h^2+\sin(h^2)}}}{1}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{2h+2 h \cos(h^2)}{2 \sqrt{h^2+\sin(h^2)}}=\lim_{h \to 0}\frac{0+0}{2\sqrt{0}}=0$$

For some reason my calculation is wrong.
Any ideas?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your use of l'Hopital gives you another $0/0$ limit, which is undefined and you can't set it equal to zero.

Instead, I suggest writing
$$\frac{\sqrt{h^2+sin(h^2)}}{h} = \frac{|h| \sqrt{1 +{ sin(h^2) \over h^2}}}{h} $$
Now try to see if this expression has a limit as $h$ goes to zero.

Comment: Oh you'r right my I got confused, too much math for today, thanks for you answer!

Answer (score 1):

The use of equivalents is simpler than L'Hôpital's rule here: $\sqrt{h^2+\sin(h^2)}\sim_0 \sqrt{2h^2}=\sqrt 2\lvert h\rvert$. So there's no limit for the quotient, only a right limit and a left limit.